# Is it possible in Java to narrow down generic type in subclass of generic class?

Tags: java, generics, types

is it possible in Java to narrow down the generic type in a subclass of a generic class?
My case looks like this:

```java
class C<T> {
  protected T foo() {...}
  protected void bar(Supplier<T> foobar) {...}
}

class A<T extends B> extends C<T> {
  public void someMethod(){
    B b = foo(); // Compiler does not complain
    bar(() -> createB()); // Compiler complains with "Type mismatch: cannot convert from B to T"
  }
}
```

Maybe what I did is totally stupid, but I don't get why the compiler does not complain about foo(), but about bar().

Any advice on how to do this, or why not to do this at all, is highly appreciated :)

Kind regards,
Thomas

Comment: where is `createB` and `B`?

Comment: `T` is a `B` but `B` does not have to be a `T`. `class D extends B {}` breaks in the second case but obviously you can assign a `D` to a `B`.

Comment: OMG you are so right. In order to fix this "createB()" also hast to be generic with type T! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a variance issue. You have `A<T extends B>` a subtype of `C<T>`. We also have

```
class C<T> {
  protected T foo() {...}
  protected void bar(Supplier<T> foobar) {...}
}
```

Now, when you do

```
B b = foo();
```

`foo()` returns `T`. And we know (from the class declaration) that `T extends B` is true. It's always safe to upcast to a supertype, so every `T` is a `B`. Now consider

```
bar(() -> createB());
```

`createB` is, I presume, a function which returns a `B`. `bar` is expecting a `Supplier<T>`. That is, `bar` is expecting something which produces a `T`. Does `createB` produce a `T`? Well, it produces a `B`. Can we upcast a `B` to a `T`? No, we know `T extends B`, but to upcast `B` to `T` we would need to know the opposite: that `B extends T`.

The `T` in `bar` appears in argument position (contravariant), while the `T` in `foo` appears in return position (covariant). This accounts for the difference in the ability to cast. Had we written

```
class A<T super B> extends C<T> {
  ...
}
```

Then you'd be able to do the `bar` example but not the `foo` example, because we have the opposite relation.

See [What is PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super), which is related to this question. It's more about call-site variance, but the discussion of variance is still relevant nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

According to @luk2302 comment: createB hast to be generic itself so that you can parameterize IT to return a `T extends b`